# How to convert an integer into a string in Classic ASP

Tags: string, cookies, asp-classic, integer, session-variables

On the home page of my site, I'm creating a session variable like this:

```
Session("doubleCookie") = DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", now)
```

I then also create a cookie using the same variable.

When a user submits a form, I call the session variable and the cookie to make sure they match. If they do, then the form will submit and if they don't, then the form will fail. The problem I'm having is, while the two are spitting out the same number, I think one is an **INT**, and the other is a **String**.

How do I ensure both variables are strings so that I can compare them to each other?

Comment: When the response.write makes sense, but the results don't, its almost always a data type issue.  And in ASP Classic, its a simple as NameType(Variable) to have it output the data type so you can verify your theory.  Obviously this was already fixed with cstr() but, in the future with ASP classic, NameType() is there for you if you have a hunch this is happening again elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method `cstr()` to transform an INT variable into a STRING.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and help. I've been a PHP dev for while, but I'm new to ASP and this was stumping me pretty good.